# Debug what plugin is changeing woocommerce order status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Something is changing the status of orders in my woocommerce store from processing to pending. I want to log what it is to the file. I have such a code:

```
function log_woocommerce_order_status_change($order_id, $old_status, $new_status) {
    $current_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $call_stack = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, 5);
    $plugin_info = 'Plugin info not available';

    foreach ($call_stack as $trace) {
        if (isset($trace['file']) && strpos($trace['file'], 'plugins/') !== false) {
            $plugin_info = 'Plugin file: ' . $trace['file'] . ', Line: ' . $trace['line'];
            break;
        }
    }

    $log_message = "[$current_datetime] woocommerce_order_status_changed hook called for order ID $order_id. Old status: $old_status, New status: $new_status. Triggered by: $plugin_info";
    error_log($log_message . PHP_EOL, 3, WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/woocommerce_order_status.log', FILE_APPEND);
}

add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'log_woocommerce_order_status_change', 10, 3);
```

But every time the status is changed it gives me the same result:

```
woocommerce_order_status_changed hook called for order ID 13232. Old status: processing, New status: pending. Triggered by: Plugin file: /home/maisonpa/domains/my-theme/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php, Line: 405
```

Is it possible to get the name of the plugin / file that directly calls the function "woocommerce_order_status_changed" and not the file in which it is stored?

Comment: Maybe debug_backtrace() ? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php  something like error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(), true)); ? Or simply disable plugin/s that you think are doing it or theme ?

Comment: My code has debug_backtracke(): "$call_stack = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, 5);"

Comment: Then describe when the status is changed ? On order creation or other event ?

Comment: I want to log every time when status is changed and what exacly changed this status

Comment: I'd start by checking what the complete backtrack has to say, instead of just logging _some_ of the info it provides (you might have simply _picked_ the wrong info.)

Answer (score 0):

for this issue first check the woocommerce settings,

Check WooCommerce Settings:
Go to your WooCommerce settings and check the "Order Status" settings under "WooCommerce" > "Settings" > "General" tab. Make sure the default order status for new orders is set to "**Processing**" if that's what you want.

Thanks